# Displays a specific number of elements in foreach PHP

Tags: php, xpath, foreach

I have to process a huge XML file, I used DOMDocument to process But the datas returned is huge, so how can I choose specific amount of elements to display.
For example I want to display 5 elements.
My code:

```
<?php
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->load('IPCCPC-epoxif-201905.xml'); //IPCCPC-epoxif-201905
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
     if(empty($_POST['search'])){
         $txtSearch = 'A01B1/00';
         }
     else{
         $txtSearch = $_POST['search'];
         }
   $titles = $xpath->query("Doc/Fld[@name='IC']/Prg/Sen[contains(text(),\"$txtSearch\")]"); 
   foreach ($titles as $title)
     {
      // I want to display 5 results here.
     }
```

Comment: if you want to only show 5, just use or initialize a counter, then increment inside the loop, stop when it reaches 5

Comment: $length = count($titles);
$length = $length>5?5:$length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $titles[$i];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index to the loop, and break out when it hits the limit.

```
$limit = 5;
foreach ($titles as $i => $title) {
    if ($i >= $limit) {
        break;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```